# Node.js MVC App with sqlite not fully operational

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, model-view-controller, hapi.js

Trying to delve into Node.js terminology and functionality. Been consulting the following MVC example **https://www.sitepoint.com/node-js-mvc-application/** that also has its GitHub repository **https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/notes-board**. However, when I build the app with all npm installed packages, except sqlite3 (I installed version 5), app is irresponsive in case there is a need to write to sqlite db, however it is able to read and delete any queries, but when there is a need to publish, it simply does not show any reactions. I am banging my head for a while now, so is there any advice or instruction out there what to do....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem sorted!

Comment: if you did something which solved your problem, you can write an answer and mark it as the accepted one.